# Select random rows until threshold value from other column is reached

Tags: r, dataframe, random, r-sf, sampling

I have an SF-object in R. It looks as follows:

```
Type   Value   Geometry 
A       1        ()
A       3        ()
B       2        ()
A       1        ()
C       4        ()
```

In the geometry column, the geometry of the polygon feature is stored.
I want to sample random rows, until a threshold-value (let's say 5) as the sum of the values in the `Value` column is reached or exceeded.

If in the example above, Rows 1, 4, and 5 are sampled, the sampling stops.

Comment: Sample with replacement?  Keep the final sample that pushes over threshold value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a while loop to check the sum on each iteration:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(type = c('a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'c'), value = c(1, 3, 2, 1, 4))
samples <- tibble()
sample_sum <- 0

while (sample_sum < 5) {
  ix <- sample(1:nrow(df), size = 1, replace = TRUE)
  samples <- bind_rows(samples, slice(df, ix))
  sample_sum <- sum(samples$value)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, for me this was the most easy solution. Got it working with my actual dataset. Will be reading up on While Loops. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Assumptions:

1. A row cannot be selected more than once
2. You want to keep the row that pushes you over the 'limit' of 5

### tidyverse version:

```
df <- tibble(type = c('a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'c'), value = c(1, 3, 2, 1, 4))
set.seed(42)
df[sample(nrow(df)),] |> 
  mutate(cumsum = cumsum(value)) |> 
  filter(lag(cumsum,1, default = 0) < 5) |> 
  select(-cumsum)

# A tibble: 2 × 2
  type  value
  <chr> <dbl>
1 a         1
2 c         4
```

This randomizes the rows in your DF, makes a cumumlative sum of 'value' and filters out all rows after you cross the cumsum limit of 5.

I've used 'lag' to ensure you get the row where you cross the limit as well.

Four trials:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 2
  type  value
  <chr> <dbl>
1 a         1
2 b         2
3 a         1
4 a         3

# A tibble: 2 × 2
  type  value
  <chr> <dbl>
1 c         4
2 a         1

# A tibble: 3 × 2
  type  value
  <chr> <dbl>
1 a         3
2 a         1
3 c         4

# A tibble: 4 × 2
  type  value
  <chr> <dbl>
1 b         2
2 a         1
3 a         1
4 c         4
```

### Base R version:

```
df[sample(nrow(df)),] |> {\(x) `[`(x, c(TRUE,head(cumsum(x$value) < 5, -1)),)}()
```

Explanation:

```
df[sample(nrow(df)),]
```

Gives you the data set in random row order.

```
 |> {\(x) `[`(x,  ....  ,)}()
```

is just a way to use `[]` subsetting in a base pipe.

```
c(TRUE,head(cumsum(x$value) < 5, -1))
```

Selects the rows where the sum is less than five, plus the row it goes over  five.

Comment: OK, this is actually much more efficient

Comment: @M-- it does fall apart a bit it if replacement is required of course!

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this is the most efficient way, but you can make a subset in a for-loop, remove the rows picked up in each step, and calculate the sum of values in your subset and stop if you've reached the threshold. I am assuming sampling without replacement.

```r
df1 <- read.table(text = "Type   Value   Geometry 
A       1        ()
A       3        ()
B       2        ()
A       1        ()
C       4        ()", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)

df1_step <- df1
df1_subset <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = ncol(df1), nrow = 0))

set.seed(123)

for(i in seq_len(nrow(df1))){
  sub_id <- sample(seq_len(nrow(df1_step)), size = 1)
  df1_subset <- rbind(df1_subset, df1_step[sub_id,])
  df1_step <- df1_step[-sub_id,]
  if (sum(df1_subset$Value) >= 5) { break }
}

## sample
df1_subset
#>   Type Value Geometry
#> 3    B     2       ()
#> 2    A     3       ()

## rows that were not picked up
df1_step
#>   Type Value Geometry
#> 1    A     1       ()
#> 4    A     1       ()
#> 5    C     4       ()
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>